# Why does my UDP message from Android not work?

Tags: java, android, udp

I have written a small java code script that sends a message via UDP to a server on my computer:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    try {
        DatagramSocket clientSocket = new DatagramSocket();
        InetAddress IP = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.1.5");
        byte[] sendData = new byte[1024];
        String sentence = "HELLO";

        sendData = sentence.getBytes();

        DatagramPacket sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(sendData, sendData.length, IP, 9876);
        clientSocket.send(sendPacket);

        clientSocket.close();
    } catch(IOException e) {

    }
}
```

I have tried the same code from another computer on the network, and the message is then correctly sent and received. When I am trying to run this from my Android phone, the server wont receive it. Why is that?

EDIT

I had forgot to add internet permisson in the manifest, but when I did that, the app crashes when I click the button:

```
06-13 21:14:26.932  13501-13501/com.example.omgandroid E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
        at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1144)
        at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.sendto(BlockGuardOs.java:175)
        at libcore.io.IoBridge.sendto(IoBridge.java:466)
        at java.net.PlainDatagramSocketImpl.send(PlainDatagramSocketImpl.java:182)
        at java.net.DatagramSocket.send(DatagramSocket.java:284)
        at com.example.omgandroid.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:72)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4475)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18786)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-13 21:14:38.987  13501-13501/com.example.omgandroid I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 13501 SIG: 9
```

What could be the cause of this?

Comment: if your android phone using your local network? if it's going out via cellular data, the `192.168` network block cannot be used - they're "private" blocks and are not routable. Your cell data provider would literally have **NO** idea where this IP address is.

Comment: The phone is of course connected to the Wifi, but I am not shure whether the message is sent via the wifi or 3g. How do I know that?

Comment: Check the exception you are catching and see if anything is turning up there. My guess is that you forgot to ask for internet permissions in your Android manifest.

Comment: You where right! But now another problem appears, see the original post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android doesn't allow network connections from the main thread (`NetworkOnMainThreadException`), to not block the user interface. They want the user interface to be responsive and not blocked by network operations, so the user won't think that the app crashed.

You have to do the network stuff inside a new thread.

[AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) is good for that.